# Using Jinja with Materialize's collapsible element doesn't display

Tags: python, mongodb, jinja2, materialize

I'm using Python and jinja, PyMongo to create a simple recipe database site. I have it connected with my MongoDB and the Jinja block content is working fine displaying the info from that DB. I want to use a Materialize collapsible element, which, when I implement on its own works fine also. When I try to combine the two and add a simple for loop in Jinja the Materialize collapsible element stops working. Where am I going wrong?

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %} {% for recipe in recipes %} {{recipe.recipe_name}} {{recipe.course_name}} {{recipe.course_description}} {{recipe.cooking_time}} {{recipe.preparation_time}} {{recipe.course_ingredients}} {% endfor %}

<ul class="collapsible popout">
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

It displays the block content from the DB fine and also the collapsible element. *See picture below*

[image: working code]

Once I wrap the collapsible element in a for loop it stops working. The block content at top still displays but the collapsible space is blank.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %} {% for recipe in recipes %} {{recipe.recipe_name}} {{recipe.course_name}} {{recipe.course_description}} {{recipe.cooking_time}} {{recipe.preparation_time}} {{recipe.course_ingredients}} {% endfor %}

<ul class="collapsible popout">
    {% for recipe in recipes %}
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Granted that isn't the finished code as I haven't implemented any block elements there but I just wanted to show it. Below is the finished code and what I thought should work. Output still shows Block code at top but no collapsible element.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %} {% for recipe in recipes %} {{recipe.recipe_name}} {{recipe.course_name}} 
{{recipe.course_description}} {{recipe.cooking_time}} {{recipe.preparation_time}} {{recipe.course_ingredients}} {% endfor %}


<ul class="collapsible popout">
    {% for recipe in recipes %}
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>{{recipe.recipe_name}} - {{recipe.course_name}}
        </div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <span>{{recipe.course_description}}</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}


</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

[image]

I can't see where my code is incorrect and doesn't render the materialize element. If any further information is needed let me know.

**Scripts**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```